# SQL Database Functions

Tags: mysql, sql, derived-table

I am trying to use this to count how many tweets has each user contributed and put it in a new column called numTwt:

```
SELECT screnname, count(*) AS numTwt
FROM Tweet
GROUP BY Tweetid
ORDER BY numTwt
```

But it seems it doesn't work.

Comment: define: `But it seems it doesn't work.`

Comment: What is your data? What's your result? And what is the expected resut?

Comment: I need to find out the number of tweets each user has contributed to the dataset I have collected.

Comment: Why do you select one thing, and then group by the other thing?

Comment: The numTwt is empty column variable I need to sort them there.

Answer (score 0):

it doesn't work because you have Tweetid in the Group By but you aren't selecting it, and you have screenname in the select, but not in the group by try this...

```
SELECT screenname, COUNT(*) AS numTwt 
FROM Tweet 
GROUP BY screenname 
ORDER BY COUNT(*)
```

I don't think you can order by an alias either

Comment: Why don't you check first?

Comment: @Strawberry: mmeasor is right. It doesn't work - or at least not properly. MySQL allows invalid `group by` usages but will return random result in that case (they call it inderminate - for all practical purposes it's random). See here for more details: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/09/06/wrong-group-by-makes-your-queries-fragile/

Comment: You *can* order by an alias though.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I was referring to the alias bit

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT screnname, count(*) AS numTwt
FROM Tweet
GROUP BY screenname, Tweetid
ORDER BY numTwt
```